# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) Bitcode Fix NOT Working

Tags: ios, xcode, clang, invocation, bitcode

I'm trying to move an Xcode app from a MBP to an iMac. I've copied all the folders and files needed but keep getting to following error on build:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

After Googling around a bit the most common fix for this is to set Bitcode to no. I've done this but it doesn't make a difference. I've also tried quitting Xcode emptying the DerivedData folder and restarting.

Below is the error in Full:

[image: Full Xcode error]

Here is a list of my linked libraries:

[image: Linked Libraries]

Comment: It seems the `libWikitudeSDK.a` file is under your desktop/TestingAugs copy/ folder? Move it to your project folder and try it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few headaches with this I decided to simply remove all references to the Wikitude lib as it was not being used by the app.

This immediately solved the issue. Thanks for those who answered.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a lot like the error is true - have you definitely got your libWikitude framework in a referenced path?

Go to XCode, Build Settings, find 'Framework Search Paths' under Search Paths, and make sure the folder of your libWikitude is correct.

Perhaps it's hardcoded and now the path has changed?